# How can i save generate otp code in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am register user by phone number as username. When i enter phone number then a otp number generate and save it on database. I have generating opt number but i can`t save it. So, how can i save it ?

My serializers.py File

```
class AccountsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate_phone_number(self, phone_number):
        if phone_number:
            MOBILE_REGEX = re.compile('^(?:\+?88)?01[13-9]\d{8}$')
            if MOBILE_REGEX.match(phone_number):
                return (phone_number)
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError('No. not matching')
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Please enter a number')

    def generate_otp(self):
        otp = randint(000000, 999999)
        return otp

    class Meta:
        model = TempRegistration
        fields = ['phone_number']
```

views.py

```
class GetPhoneNumber(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = TempRegistration.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountsSerializer
```

models.py

```
class TempRegistration(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    otp_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the **`perform_create(...)`** method of **`GetPhoneNumber`** view

```
class GetPhoneNumber(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = TempRegistration.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountsSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(otp_code=randint(000000, 999999))
```